# python shared dictionary using ray?

Tags: python, ray

Reading Ray [docs](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/serialization.html) I see it supports serialization of `dicts` natively ("Serialize directly"),
But I cannot understand what that means, Or what should I do to use those serialized objects.
Given that I have the following flow:

```
import ray
ray.init()

dict_1 = {}
dict_2 = {}

@ray.remote
def f(x):
    dict_1[x] = x*x
    dict_2[x] = x*x*x
    return x

futures = [f.remote(i) for i in range(4)]
print(ray.get(futures))
```

Should I do something to gureentee thread-safe behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

ray remote functions are running in different "processes". This means when you run 4 different remote calls, it will have different address space (so, what you are doing in your code is basically not that useful). What it means by serialization is that when you call `f.remote` with an argument `i`, the object i (which is your argument) should be serialized because it will be sent to other processes (so that Ray supports parallelization). Ray makes this process very fast using shared memory for big objects.

Also, if you want to have shared states, you can use actors (https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/actors.html). When you use actor, you don't need to care about thread safety because state updates for actors are happening in the order where the actor is called.

Comment: So with actors, the global dictionaries would be still globals? outside the actor?

Comment: No, it isn't possible to have global variables that are shared between all of the processes in precisely the way you are trying to do it (in your example, there would be a separate copy of the dictionary in the main script and in the worker process). Actors have state that can be mutated, but to access that state from the main script, the main script would need to call a method on the actor that returns the relevant state.